# How to copy values from a structure to a char array

Tags: c, project

Sorry if question is not clear. My vocabulary for terminology is bad. Anyways I want to set a string to be a structure. For example if my strucutre is define as:

```
struct all_routes{
  int id;
  char departure_code[4];
  char arrival_code[4];
};
struct all_routes all_routes_divid[500];
```

I add I want to set a string to contain values taken from one of the elements of this array of structures:

```
char firs_airport_code[4] = all_routes_divid[1].departure_code;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I am not certain what is required, but do you really want to just copy bytes from one string to another? We can get clearer by asking "what would you like to see in the string for the a value in `all_routes_divid[1].id`?" Do you want a binary value, which is very unlikely to be printable in any useful way, or do you want a printable value? You might be trying to create a printable string, in which case sprintf is needed. For example, if you wanted a nicely formatted string for output, you might do sprintf(airport_id, "%06d", all_routes_divid[1].id);` Of course, I might be wrong :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) -

```
char firs_airport_code[4]; 
......
strcpy(firs_airport_code, all_routes_divid[1].departure_code);
```

Or by using [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/) -

```
char firs_airport_code[4]; 
......
memcpy(firs_airport_code, all_routes_divid[1].departure_code, 4);
```

Or by using [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/) -

```
char firs_airport_code[4]; 
......
strncpy(firs_airport_code, all_routes_divid[1].departure_code, 4);
```

I would suggest to use `strcpy` for simplicity (because it is common for copying strings and the name is also intuitive ;-) ). But sometimes `memcpy` performs faster than `strcpy` because it moves blocks of memory at a time which allows it to perform some optimization (I will not go into details here).

Comment: This works too. But is there another way such as pointing `first_airport_code to` to `all_routes_divid[1].departure_code`?

Comment: @LearningC: No, I don't think so. You could have pointed `first_airport_code` to `all_routes_divid[1].departure_code` if it was a pointer, which it's not. It's an array, although implicitly being treated as a pointer. So if you try to point `first_airport_code` to that array, C won't allow it.

Comment: `str(n)cpy` is definitely the way to go.